# Integrate new rails app with existing external MS SQL Server database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, database

I need to create a new rails application that will use an existing external Microsoft SQL server database as its primary database. This DB is running on an external server that i'll need to connect to. Here where i work there's a separate DB Admins section so im not sure what steps i need to perform. I think the easy part is connect to the server and set the app to work with that DB. But i get confused after that.

Should i create a db dump and migration?

Should i add models to represent existing database structure?

In case i need to create new models and tables in the db...

Should i generate its models from the rails generator and run migrations on the db or contact the DB admins to create the tables, and then specify manually the models inside the app? **<- this really confuses me**

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english! :)

**EDIT!! -> *The Rails Way***

I've found another great way to integrate multiple database data... You can define a model and specify in which database it's located (so db connection is never closed)... This is definitely *The Rails Way* and should be followed...

Here's a nice tut: 
[Multiple Databases in Rails](http://imnithin.in/multiple-database.html)

**TL;DR**

1. Define your secondary_db in database.yml
2. Define your model and specify its database and table name

   ```
   Class ExternalDatabaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
     establish_connection(:secondary_db)
     self.table_name = "the_table"
     self.primary_key = 'someWeirdIDColumn'
   end
   ```

Then use as any other rails model, specify relationships and more :)

Hope it helps to somebody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at tiny tds gem: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds. It's really use to config and use... you can use it to connect on your external sql server db and make the queries you want. Don't know which type of system you're working, but if you're constantly retrieving data, making external requests may get your system slower. Depending on your application, you could consider synchronizing the data, making a local database redundant. Hope it helps you, good luck!

EDIT: about the models part: if you're going to retrieve the data from that sql server every time you need, than you don't need to store it locally. But if you're doing that redundancy, you should create the models with the attributes you'll need, than when you retrieve from the server, you save it normally, just attributing the values to your model and calling `save!` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've been reading about tiny_tds and the sql-server-adapter gem but i get confused because i think this db will be the primary and only db, i mean, i think there wont be any other db to store data, so i dont know how to handle that. (there wont be -much- speed troubles as its all intranet). Is that a thing or am i overthinking this?

Comment: Got it. So, in that case, are you gonna do only queries to retrieve data, or are you gonna modify that data too? Anyway, basically, you're gonna need an user on the sql server with the permissions to do the actions you need (read and/or write), than you configure that user in tiny_tds gem, as well as the address and port for your sql server host. With that, every time you need in your application, you do a sql query call to the server, to retrieve or save the data. Hope this makes it clear

Comment: Thanks! I like that approach, so in addition to the external queries, the app will have it's own database to store app-related data with its own mapping (models). Have a great day!